# Django Reusable Apps and migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-south

I am trying to create a 'Reusable App'. I've written some database models, and then copy/pasted the folder (which is supposed to be my reusable app) into the Project I want to be using it in. I then added the folder's name to `INSTALLED_APPS` in my settings.

Then I used South to run:

```
python manage.py schemamigration test --initial --settings=settings_local
```

and:

```
python manage.py migrate test --settings=settings_local
```

When I tried accessing this app's models in the admin I got a `relation does not exist`. I went in my PostgreSQL and realized the tables were not created with those South commands.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I am using `Django 1.5.10` and `South 0.7.5`

The migration that is created when running schemma migration

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding model 'Category'
        db.create_table(u'test_category', (
            (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
            ('name', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(unique=True, max_length=200)),
        ))
        db.send_create_signal(u'test', ['Category'])


    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting model 'Category'
        db.delete_table(u'test_category')


    models = {
        u'test.category': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'Category'},
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '200'})
        }
    }

    complete_apps = ['test']
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your south commands. Is the migration that it created correct? Does it contain the code to create the tables you expect?

Comment: I'm assuming your app is named test?   Also you're using something older than django 1.7?  you won't use South after upgrading to Django 1.7.   I've personally not had experience with the command settings=settings_local.  I usually just type...

python manage.py schemamigration test --initial then python manage.py migrate test

Comment: @marksweb i have updated my question with the migration and it looks like its correct

Comment: @ChrisHawkes i am using Django 1.5

Comment: @psychok7 there's nothing wrong with your migration. Do you get any errors? Does your `south_migrationhistroy` table show the migration as being applied?

Comment: @marksweb yes, when i do the migrate --list command  it shows it has applied my migration. but i cant find it on my db if i go directly and i get the relation does not exist error in the admin

Comment: @psychok7 Right, can you zip up your app & I can try to install it? I'm on MySQL DBs for all my projects so I can see how that goes.

Comment: @marksweb here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zby09fcd9580fc/django-ubiwhere-games-0.1.tar.gz?dl=0 . this version has a few more stuff and different names but the issues are the same basically. I am using PostGreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've generated the migrations and installed the app in a project of mine without a problem with a MySQL Db.

I've not really changed anything, but I did fix an import error in your form.

Your form inherits `BaseInlineFormSet` which you tried to import from `django.forms` but it should be imported from;

`from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet`

I've zipped up the app as it is running in my project;
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqyi9su942rsp1u/ubiwhere_games.zip?dl=0

Comment: didnt you have to run migrate?? are you able to write to the reusable apps tables without issues?

Comment: Yeah it's fine. I've added a Quiz question.

Comment: you generated the migrations from inside your own PROJECT right? after adding mine to your installed apps i am assuming?

Comment: I did, but a migration isn't project specific. You should be able to apply the exact same migration as I included in that zip and run the app as I have. If you can't then I can only assume there is an issue with PostGres.

Comment: it started working. i am not sure exactly why, but it seems like i had 2 models with the same name in different apps for some reason they were clashing.. thanks for your help